# Java Spark job submission using the Delta Lake library

Tags: java, apache-spark, delta-lake

I am trying to run a spark submit job in order to access the Delta Lake buckets.

The spark submit command which i am giving is as :

```
 command: [
        "/bin/sh",
        "-c",
        "/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
      --master k8s://https://kubernetes.default.svc \
      --deploy-mode cluster \
      --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=123456789.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/poc:v9 \
      --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Divy.cache.dir=/tmp -Divy.home=/tmp' \
      --conf spark.app.name=txn-poc \
      --conf spark.jars.ivy=/tmp/.ivy \
      --conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.HTTP2_DISABLE=true \
      --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=argo \
      --conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
      --packages org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4 \
      --packages io.delta:delta-standalone_2.13:1.1.0 \
      --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.13:1.1.0  \
      --packages org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.8 \
      --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1 \
      --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=txn \
      --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores=1000m \
      --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.request.cores=500m \
      --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=default \
      --conf spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension \
      --conf spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog \
      --class com.arcesium.performa.data.table.pipeline.app.SparkPOCApp \
```

When running its giving error in finding the Delta Lake packages
Following error is seen when running it

```
22/05/18 08:45:52 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, txn-poc-6cff5980d657babc-driver-svc.argo.svc, 7079, None)
22/05/18 08:45:59 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend$KubernetesDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (10.0.2.236:52042) with ID 1,  ResourceProfileId 0
22/05/18 08:45:59 INFO KubernetesClusterSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.8
22/05/18 08:45:59 WARN SparkSession: Cannot use io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension to configure session extensions.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:216)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.$anonfun$applyExtensions$1(SparkSession.scala:1194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.$anonfun$applyExtensions$1$adapted(SparkSession.scala:1192)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$applyExtensions(SparkSess
```

Please suggest what is being missed in running arguments

Comment: what Spark version is used?

Comment: version is spark:v3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your `spark-submit`:

- there should be only one `--packages` - all packages needs to be listed separated by comma (see [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html))
- you don't need `io.delta:delta-standalone_2.13:1.1.0` and `org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.8` dependencies
- you're using wrong version of `io.delta:delta-core` library - for Spark 3.2.1 you need to use version 1.2.0 (see [compatibility matrix](https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html#compatibility-with-apache-spark)).  Plus you need to use version compiled for Scala 2.12, but you're using compiled for Scala 2.13.  So it should be `io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.2.0` instead.

Comment: getting this error after doing all recommended changes

 java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF

Comment: I believe that it's a problem in your code - do you have UDFs in it? Please ask this as a separate question, providing code snippets, etc.

Comment: public DeltaTable getDeltaTable(DataTable dataTable) {
        return DeltaTable.forPath(lakeLocation + "/" + dataTable.getTableName());
    }



This code snippet is causing issue actually